# @ConditionalOnProperty conditionally works

Tags: spring-boot

I have code like the following:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.foo.bar}")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="cron.foo.bar.enabled", relaxedNames = false)
public void parseFooBar() {
... blah blah blah ...
}
```

In my properties file, I have:

```
cron.foo.bar=1 * * * * ?
cron.foo.bar.enabled=false
```

This does not work, and parseFooBar gets executed every minute on the 1st second.

However, if I add the field:

```
@Value("${cron.foo.bar.enabled}")
private String enabledProp;
```

so that I can do a log and see what it is, parseFooBar does NOT get executed.  Removing the injected String once again sees parseFooBar execute.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is using Spring 4.1.5, Spring Boot 1.2.1, and JDK 8

Edit 2: moving the annotation to the type also works.  (without having to force the @Value).  But the annotation is both a Method and a Type annotation?  It gives me a little more flexibility to do it on the method...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A condition in Spring Framework is used to control whether or not a component is registered in the application context. From the javadoc of `@Conditional`:

> The `@Conditional` annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly annotated with `@Component`, including `@Configuration` classes
> - as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype annotations
> - as a method-level annotation on any `@Bean` method

When the condition is declared on `parseFooBar` it has no effect as it's not a `@Bean` method. It works as you expect when you declare it on the type as it then makes the component conditional such that it's not registered in the application context when the property doesn't match.

Comment: thanks.  I've now refactored so that each of my \@Scheduled methods is itself in a separate bean, headed by the \@ConditionalOnProperty annotation.  There's now an explosion of beans, but at least everything is configurable and readable.