# Stop Spring @Controller at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've found [Can a spring boot @RestController be enabled/disabled using properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958231) which addresses not starting a @Controller at boot time, but I'm looking for a way to stop a @Controller at runtime.

Comment: Hm, since every @Controller is a regular bean I can probably destroy it like every other bean by retrieving it from the context as `DefaultListableBeanFactory` and call `destroySingleton()` with the bean's name.

Comment: Why do you need to destroy it? You could also return a 404 with an if (certain circunstance) ...

Answer (score 3):

I would actually used the @RefreshScope Bean and then when you want to stop the Rest Controller at runtime, you only need to change the property of said controller to false.

SO's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737305/refreshscope-runtime-configuration-without-spring-cloud-config-server) referencing to changing property at runtime.

Here are my snippets of working code:

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
class MessageRestController(
    @Value("\${message.get.enabled}") val getEnabled: Boolean,
    @Value("\${message:Hello default}") val message: String
) {
    @GetMapping("/message")
    fun get(): String {
        if (!getEnabled) {
            throw NoHandlerFoundException("GET", "/message", null)
        }
        return message
    }
}
```

And there are other alternatives of using Filter:

```
@Component
class EndpointsAvailabilityFilter @Autowired constructor(
    private val env: Environment
): OncePerRequestFilter() {
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val requestURI = request.requestURI
        val requestMethod = request.method
        val property = "${requestURI.substring(1).replace("/", ".")}." +
                "${requestMethod.toLowerCase()}.enabled"
        val enabled = env.getProperty(property, "true")
        if (!enabled.toBoolean()) {
            throw NoHandlerFoundException(requestMethod, requestURI, ServletServerHttpRequest(request).headers)
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

[My Github explaining how to disable at runtime](https://github.com/david-blacnet/spring-config-example)

Comment: @Andras Hatvani, does this answer your question?