# Is it possible to optionally load SpringBoot endpoints?

Tags: spring-boot

We have a web application that we would like to run in 'batch' mode, in this mode we dont want any endpoints exposed (for security reasons).

Is this possible in SpringBoot ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a spring boot @RestController be enabled/disabled using properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958231/can-a-spring-boot-restcontroller-be-enabled-disabled-using-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you use profiles on `@Controller` or `@RestController` classes:

```
@Profile("!batch")
@RestController
public class SomeController { 
...
}
```

This means, `SomeController` will be created for the application, if the profile is anything but `batch`.

Then, you can run without `batch` profile and have the endpoints; or activate the profile via property, environment or from command line with the `batch` profile:

```
java -jar some-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=batch
```

See Spring [API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) for details on how to define and activate profiles