# Enable ConditionalOnProperty in a RequestMapping in Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a piece of code -

```
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:securityConfig.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
    @Controller
    public class IndexController {
        private static final String LOGIN_PAGE           = "login";
        private static final String HOME_PAGE            = "home";
        private static final String LOBBY_PAGE           = "lobby";
        private static final String FORGOT_USER_PAGE     = "forgotUserName";
        private static final String FORGOT_PASSWORD_PAGE = "forgotPassWord";

        @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "auth.mode", havingValue = "fixed")
        @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = { "/login" })
        public String getIndexPage() {
            return LOGIN_PAGE;
        }
}
```

However, the ConditionalOn annotation doesnt work as expected. I do not want the controller to execute if `auth.mode` is anything other than `fixed`. Note - `auth.mode` is in `securityConfig.properties` file

Am I missing something? Probably an annotation at class level?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958231/can-a-spring-boot-restcontroller-be-enabled-disabled-using-properties

Comment: @Héctor it didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation to the class, not on the method.

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:securityConfig.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Controller
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "auth.mode", havingValue = "fixed")
public class IndexController {
    ...
}
```

This will mean the entire controller will not exist in the application context unless the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to add the condition

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:securityConfig.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    private static final String LOGIN_PAGE           = "login";
    private static final String HOME_PAGE            = "home";
    private static final String LOBBY_PAGE           = "lobby";
    private static final String FORGOT_USER_PAGE     = "forgotUserName";
    private static final String FORGOT_PASSWORD_PAGE = "forgotPassWord";

    @Value("${auth.mode:fixed}")
    private String authenticationMode;

    public String getAuthenticationMode(){
         return this.authenticationMode;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous() AND this.getAuthenticationMode().equals(\"fixed\")")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = { "/login" })
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return LOGIN_PAGE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ConditionalOnProperty` can be used as a **method**-level annotation [only](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) on `@Bean` method like (in a configuration class):

```
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.feature.enabled", havingValue = "true")
  public MyFeature myFeature() {
      // create and return MyFeature instance
  }
```

I personally used a `@Value` annotation that loads a property, and then uses a conditional structure (a `if`) according to the property value.

Like in:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my-endpoint")
public class MyController {

  @Value("${myapp.my-config-value}")
  private String myConfigValue;

  @GetMapping
  public String myMethod() {
    if ("disable".equals(myConfigValue)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("This service is disabled.");
    }
    // if not disabled, do your stuff
    return myService.doStuff();
  }

}
```