# Temporary disable REST endpoints in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

During startup, we need to do some adjustments for the application. We want to make REST API temporarily unavailable to be sure that there will be no concurrent updates. After adjustment is done, we would like to enable REST API and start serving requests. Is it possible to disable temporary REST API in Spring Boot?

Comment: You might look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958231/can-a-spring-boot-restcontroller-be-enabled-disabled-using-properties or (https://www.togglz.org/) if you would like to do this on demand.

Comment: In this case, we would need to add @ConditionalOnExpression annotation to each REST endpoint and also it won't allow us to enable/disable them in runtime.

Comment: Which deployment env do you use?

Comment: Didn't get the question. I need it for all envs

Comment: @Sydorov found any thing ? searching for the same..!