# In Spring Boot, can I disable a @RestController (that is @Import'ed) from a 3rd party?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, graphql-java

The key is that the `@RestController` class is from a 3rd party package that I can't touch. I want all the other classes in that package but not a particular `@RestController` because I want to replace those endpoints with my own.

It also seems this class is @Import'ed by another class that's also in the 3rd party package that I don't control (see Edit3 below)

It's similar to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958231/can-a-spring-boot-restcontroller-be-enabled-disabled-using-properties), however in that question, OP has access to the @RestController and can append a @ConditionalOnExpression, whereas I cannot.

Is there another way to disable a @RestController in spring?

The specific @RestController class I want to disable is [GraphQLController](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/graphql-kickstart-spring-webflux/src/main/java/graphql/kickstart/spring/webflux/GraphQLController.java).

**Edit1**

Here are some ways I tried to exclude it but fails

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.mycomp.package")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController.class})
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

The above attempt throws a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
> - graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController

As suggested below, I also tried `@ComponentScan.Filter` of `ASSIGNABLE_TYPE`

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.mycomp.package")
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController.class)})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  ....
}
```

No errors but it's still instantiating the bean.

Also tried `@ComponentScan.Filter` of `REGEX`

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.mycomp.package")
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController")})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  ....
}
```

That didn't seem to work either

Also tried `@ComponentScan.Filter` of `CUSTOM`

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.mycomp.package")
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
    classes = GraphQLControllerBeanFilter.class))
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  ....
}

public class GraphQLControllerBeanFilter implements TypeFilter {

  @Override
  public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader,
      MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {
    ClassMetadata classMetadata = metadataReader.getClassMetadata();
    String fullyQualifiedName = classMetadata.getClassName();
    return fullyQualifiedName.equals("graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController");    
  }
}
```

The custom filter doesn't seem to ever see the `GraphQLController`. In fact, I printed out all the `fullyQualifiedName` it scans and only the ones in my `com.mycomp.package` package show. Nothing from 3rd party libraries even though it's loading them.

I'm wondering if the `@ComponentScan.Filter` ever sees 3rd party packages or if maybe I have some other spring setting overriding it.

I also tried adding `@Primary` to my Controller

```
@Primary
@RestController
public class MyGraphQLController extends graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController
```

But that results in this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController'

**Edit2**

This is the 3rd party library that contains the @RestController I'm trying to exclude

```
implementation "com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-starter-webflux:11.0.0"
```

**Edit3**

It looks like [graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.boot.GraphQLSpringWebfluxAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/web/reactive/GraphQLSpringWebfluxAutoConfiguration.java#L55) is importing the `GraphQLController` in an `@Import` annotation.

Is there anyway to disable or replace it in this case?

Comment: Can you provide setup to enable `GraphQLController`? I can disable a Controller created in local using `@ComponentScan.Filter`.

Comment: I provided the package coordinates that enables `GraphQLController` in **Edit2**.

Comment: You can use spring securty to block access to certain paths

Comment: @Antoniossss That's an interesting idea. It would not be ideal for me in this case because the path is determined by `GraphQLController`'s parent class `AbstractGraphQLController` and I actually want to inject my own implementation of `GraphQLController`. So I don't want to block the endpoint, I want to replace the implementation

Comment: I think you can override `GraphQLController` by implementing your own class and add `@Primary` to it.

Comment: I don't see `GraphQLController` bean by adding the dependency stated. I check with following method.
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }

Comment: @GrigoriiRiabov I tried `@Primary` but something is still trying to map the original bean because I get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'graphql.kickstart.spring.webflux.GraphQLController' method `

Comment: @kane, can you attach the code of the class that overrides `GraphQLController`?

Comment: @GrigoriiRiabov I added my code that overrides `GraphQLController` in the post

Comment: I also found out that `GraphQLSpringWebfluxAutoConfiguration` explicitly @Imports the `GraphQLController`. Maybe that's why the suggested strategies aren't working

Comment: @kane try to extend to `AbstractGraphQLController` like this code: `@Primary
@RestController
public class MyGraphQLController extends AbstractGraphQLController`. You can try my [repo](https://github.com/GrinRus/graph-ql-demo) and check in spring actuator only one bean `MyGraphQLController`